# Codeigniter splitting between application and web server

Tags: php, codeigniter, server

I know this is quite a weird question but I was hoping that someone could advise me on how I can split my Codeigniter application between 2 different servers?

The solution I have in mind now is this

Web Server - The model won't be used. The View and Controller will be used. The controller will make a REST request to the Application server that will return json data to it and will push to the view

Application Server - The View won't be used. The Controller is where the business logic is at and will communicate with the model.

Is my thinking correct?

There is another way that uses PHP FPM but I am unsure of how that works.

Comment: Have you checked this [google search reslt](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Codeigniter+splitting+between+application+and+web+server&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN725IN725&oq=Codeigniter+splitting+between+application+and+web+server&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Yeah the first one is my question

Comment: i know but i was taking about other suggestions.

Comment: Sorry which ones? The other one uses a custom autoloader which doesn't seem to fulfill my requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through below mentioned solution.

IN this case you need to create REST Server where all your database related activities will be happen. You can implement REST Server in codeigniter by below mentioned link.

https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

In rest server your controller will handle specific http operation with methods. like `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `UPDATE`

```
class Books extends REST_Controller
{
  public function index_get()
  {
    // Display all books
  }

  public function index_post()
  {
    // Create a new book
  }
}
```

Now in your view part you need to implement rest client. So that you can make request for CRUD operations depends on requirement.

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient

While beauty of rest client is below.

```
// Load the library
$this->load->library('rest');

// Run some setup
$this->rest->initialize($config);

// Pull in an array of tweets
$tweets = $this->rest->get('statuses/user_timeline/'.$username.'.xml');
```

You can get response in multiple format. like `Json`, `CSV`, `XML` etc.

I have used this both and it working pretty much awesome.

Let me know if you  need any help during implementation.

Comment: One Up for me. I have never done it before but I think about using this option in future. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. I guess my method is about the same as your suggestion. I'll mark this as the right answer.

Comment: No worries, If you need any help in implementation this you get get in touch with me,